# SOQL Query for only an account w/specific name

Tags: soql

I'm trying to do a SOQL query that only queries where the Name from Account is equal to a string being passed.

```
public void getAcc(String searchField) {
  List<Account> list_acc = [Select Name, ID, LastModifiedByID from Account WHERE Name = searchField ORDER BY LastModifiedDate Asc];
}
```

This is not working since my syntax is incorrect, but kind of confused on how to check for a specific name being passed into this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the colon that needs to be placed in front of a variable when querying via apex as below:

```
public void getAcc(String searchField) {
  List<Account> list_acc = [Select Name, ID, LastModifiedByID from Account WHERE Name =: searchField ORDER BY LastModifiedDate Asc];
}
```